# Possibility to lower the comment privilege

Tags: discussion

I have notice many of the Answers are not really answers but comments made from mostly users that do not yet have the comment privilege (So they get energetic when they see a question that relates to them) and so they create an answer for it. Is there a way to somehow allow them to comment but wait for moderator to accept or deny this comment. At least it would be help when flagging.

Comment: I guess this would give less *seen* comments posted as answers but the work for moderators will be the same since they have to handle it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a good idea in theory, it's set this way to really focus new users on the core of the site: Asking questions, giving answers. Not only is the "gain rep, gain privileges" a gaming mechanism, but it's also a way to prevent shell shock for new users by throwing too many things at them at one time. It's easy enough to convert an answer to a comment and we probably deal with 5 of them a day - in the grand scheme of flags per day that's pretty low and it's a chance for us to teach new users about the whole reputation system (by leaving a comment prior to converting their answer to a comment). Furthermore, conversion of answers to comments is one way, and if a user posts an awesome answer as a comment by mistake there's no immediate way to rectify that.

[This answer also goes into the "generic" SE answer as to why there is 50 rep for commenting](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/716/why-are-you-only-allowed-to-comment-with-50-rep).

In the end, it's not a rampant issue, hence why in the three years of operation it hasn't changed in the Stack Exchange system. If you're interested in helping users out instead of just flagging, check out the [Pro-Forma comments tool](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-pro-forma-comments-do-you-use) as it has a nice "Comment as an Answer" message that you can use :)

Comment: Thanks for the good answer Marco.