# Low reputation people can't comment if they are not sure of answer

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are you only allowed to comment with 50 rep?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/716/why-are-you-only-allowed-to-comment-with-50-rep)

I am a new user to SO , to be true(3 days) , we can see other users questions, but if we are confused for an answer , we can't comment(due to low rep), so there is no choice other than posting answer.

Now, if the answer is incorrect, then others downvote , which further leads to low repu and further we can't comment.

I am facing this, may be others too.