# How do you leave a comment on a question?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are you only allowed to comment with 50 rep?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/716/why-are-you-only-allowed-to-comment-with-50-rep)

I only see a box for leaving an answer, but I can't seem to figure out how to leave a comment to a question.
I must be blind, because other people seem to be able to do it.
?

Comment: Also note that if you're trying to comment on your *own* question, or on any answer to it, you can do that even if you have less than 50 rep. But you must be logged on to Ask Ubuntu as the same user account you used to post the question. If you have multiple accounts you can request they be merged together by flagging any off your posts or by posting a [tag:support] question on meta.